# Using scoreboard objectives as arguments for commands

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to use scoreboard objectives as arguments for commands?

For example, say I have a command block that should teleport a player to a location based on their score.

```
tp Notch score_Notch_Deaths 0 0
```

This should teleport Notch to an x-coordinate based on his `Deaths` score.

If this is possible, what would the actual syntax be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How do I allow other players on my server to use commands like teleport, but not spawn in items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321110/how-do-i-allow-other-players-on-my-server-to-use-commands-like-teleport-but-not) (via bypassing duplicate chain from [Teleporting to a location defined by scoreboard objectives](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/364643/185203))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to directly use an objective as a command argument. Dinnerbone has said that the reason for this is that he wanted to avoid making commands into a full programming language.

The best you can do is something like this:

```
tp @a[score_Notch_Deaths_min=1,score_Notch_Deaths=1] 1 0 0
tp @a[score_Notch_Deaths_min=2,score_Notch_Deaths=2] 2 0 0
tp @a[score_Notch_Deaths_min=3,score_Notch_Deaths=3] 3 0 0
```

In separate command blocks, and then activate them all at once. It would be tedious to do by hand, so I'd suggest using an MCEdit filter such as [Texelelf's command block filter](http://elemanser.com/EditControl.py) to fill out the incrementing values automatically.

Comment: This is too bad; I like programming languages!

Answer (score -3):

You need to do it recursively.

do this: `/tp Notch 0 0 0`

then you need these on a fill clock

```
/tp @a[name=Notch,score_Deaths_min=1] ~1 ~ ~
/scoreboard players remove Notch Deaths 1
```

Comment: While the idea behind this answer can work, the implementation lacks several commands, such as the one keeping Deaths from decreasing into minus infinity. Furthermore, it is badly described and I could only figure out what you meant by reading the existing answer.