# How do I allow other players on my server to use commands like teleport, but not spawn in items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I play on the DivineJourney modpack with a friend, but he wants to constantly spawn things in. Is there any way to allow him to be able to use the teleport command, but not be able to spawn in items?

I've already locked the NEI mode to Recipe.

I've looked around for a mod for plug-ins for Forge (as thats what the server is on) but I couldn't find anything thats up to date. I found Sponge, but thats for 1.8+, and I need 1.7.10.

Answer (score 8):

You can't grant access to only the `/teleport` command, but you can prepare a `/trigger` for them to use.

First create three scoreboards for the coordinates:

```
/scoreboard objectives add x trigger
/scoreboard objectives add y trigger
/scoreboard objectives add z trigger
```

The `trigger` type is what allows them to be set by non-OPs.

Then you enable them for use by everyone:

```
/scoreboard players enable @a x
/scoreboard players enable @a y
/scoreboard players enable @a z
```

This should be done in a clock, because using a trigger automatically disables it for that player.

Now the players can use commands like these to set their goal coordinates:

```
/trigger x
/trigger x add 123
/trigger x set 456
```

The first of these adds 1 to the scoreboard value for that player, the rest should be obvious.

Next you need something to actually start the teleportation. You can use this with yet another trigger of which you constantly check whether someone set it to 1 for himself, you can use the classical renamed item on the ground, you can do it whenever someone jumps 100 times on the spot, etc. Instructions for all of these can be found elsewhere. I assume here that whatever mechanism you use tags the player with "`toTeleport`".

Now to the actual teleportation: You can't just say `/teleport @p <his_scoreboard_value_x>` etc., so you have to use an entity of which you can set the coordinates in NBT. An armour stand is a nice dummy entity:

```
/execute at @p[tag=toTeleport] run summon armor_stand ~ ~ ~ {Marker:1,NoGravity:1,NoAI:1,Invisible:1,Tags:["teleportHelper"]}
```

This assumes that whatever detection system you use to initialise the teleportation gives the player the `toTeleport` tag.

And this is the trick: Unlike players, other entities can be teleported anywhere using their `Pos` NBT tag, which you can set to arbitrary numbers using `/execute store`:

```
/execute store result entity @e[tag=teleportHelper,limit=1] Pos[0] double 1 run scoreboard players get @p[tag=toTeleport] x
/execute store result entity @e[tag=teleportHelper,limit=1] Pos[1] double 1 run scoreboard players get @p[tag=toTeleport] y
/execute store result entity @e[tag=teleportHelper,limit=1] Pos[2] double 1 run scoreboard players get @p[tag=toTeleport] z
```

These three commands have to be in a chain (preferably your regular looping command block chain), followed by this command:

```
/tp @p[tag=toTeleport] @e[tag=teleportHelper,limit=1]
```

It's important that you teleport the player to the armour stand in the same tick that you set the `Pos` tag in, otherwise the chunk might unload and the teleportation would fail.

Then you just clean up everything:

```
/kill @e[tag=teleportHelper]
/tag remove @p[tag=toTeleport] toTeleport
```

This system should work fine in multiplayer, even if two players activate it at the exact same time, one will just be teleported one game tick later.

<sub>Thanks to vdvman1 in the Eigencraft Discord chat who told me that `/trigger` works with numbers and that you can teleport to far away entities if they were loaded at the start of the tick.</sub>

---

This is an optimized version of the above using functions that will also handle multiplayer better, it will allow any number of players to teleport in the same tick, to their own individual destinations. Written by vdvman1.

```
# run once
scoreboard objectives add x trigger
scoreboard objectives add y trigger
scoreboard objectives add z trigger
scoreboard objectives add tp trigger
```

---

```
# run every tick
execute as @a run function tp_trigger
```

---

```
# tp_trigger.mcfunction
scoreboard players enable @s x
scoreboard players enable @s y
scoreboard players enable @s z
execute if score @s tp matches 1.. run function tp_activate
```

---

```
# tp_activate.mcfunction
scoreboard players set @s tp 0
scoreboard players enable @s tp
scoreboard players operation #current x = @s x
scoreboard players operation #current y = @s y
scoreboard players operation #current z = @s z
tag @s add tp_trigger_source
summon area_effect_cloud ~ ~ ~ {Tags:["tp_trigger_target"]}
execute as @e[type=area_effect_cloud,tag=tp_trigger_target,limit=1] run function set_pos.mcfunction
tag @s remove tp_trigger_source
```

---

```
# set_pos.mcfunction
execute store result entity @s Pos[0] double 1 run scoreboard players get #current x
execute store result entity @s Pos[1] double 1 run scoreboard players get #current y
execute store result entity @s Pos[2] double 1 run scoreboard players get #current z
execute at @s run tp @a[tag=tp_trigger_source,limit=1] ~ ~ ~
```

Answer (score 7):

Yes, using the ForgeEssentials Mod for Minecraft 1.7.10.

*This is a MOD, not a plugin, so there is no need for sponge, etc.

On their website: http://forgeessentials.com/

It details:

> Permissions
>
> FE adds the most powerful permission system ever seen  in Minecraft. Make usergroups and restrict permissions for  guests to keep your server grief-free. With over 250 basic permissions and hundreds of block- / item-based permissions there is nearly nothing you cannot do

By using their WIKI: https://github.com/ForgeEssentials/ForgeEssentials/wiki/Permissions-tutorial

We can use the permissions to do what you need.

> /p group nocheat create

This creates an empty group called "nocheat"

Then we need to deny them the "/give" permission (that is how NEI gives items to players)

> /p group nocheat deny minecraft.give minecraft.give.*

Or

> /p group nocheat deny fe.give fe.give.*

Then your friends should not be able to summon items, but still teleport!

You can also use this for all of your permissions from now on.

Answer (score 5):

Teleporting requires op permissions. There is no way to allow teleportation without other cheat commands (without external mods).

If you know all the people on your server, or if you know all the locations you want to teleport to, you could have a series of **command blocks** that could be activated. Here are some ideas:

A command block that teleports the player to:

- a specific username on the server (one command block per player).
- the nearest player
- a random player
- specific coordinates, such as a person's base or landmark (one command block per landmark).

You could then place a command block in each person's base that would take them back to spawn, where they could then choose where they'd like to go. It's not as flexible as a /tp command, but a few command blocks should be able to take care of most scenarios where players want to teleport.

Comment: Thank you for answering instead of just downvoting. I appreciate it. I am a beginner and wasn't sure, that made it clear