# Minecraft Bedrock server - allow anyone to tp

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I would like to allow anyone to `tp` without being an operator. I currently have a simple webserver that takes `tp` arguments and runs that as server, but has no security implemented. I would like people to `tp` to each other, or to coordinates, without being able to admin abuse, or at least be able to use `/kill` to kill self.

Comment: For Java Edition: [How do I allow other players on my server to use commands like teleport, but not spawn in items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/321110/185203)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These commands/functions are not natively supported by the regular [Bedrock Dedicated Server Software](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/download/server/bedrock).

If you want additional plugins without the use of `/function` or `/trigger`, you'll need to use custom software such as Nukkit or PocketMine.

[See this helpdesk article for more information](https://support.witherhosting.com/en/article/which-bedrock-software-is-for-you-1rxtz3l) (extract listed below).

Should you choose Nukkit, [there is a port of the](https://cloudburstmc.org/resources/essentialsnk.15/) [EssentialsEX](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/essentialsx.9089/) [plugin found on most Bukkit/Spigot/Sponge/Paper servers](https://cloudburstmc.org/resources/essentialsnk.15/) that'll contain your `/tpa`, `/tpaccept` and `/tpdeny` commands.

Then, enable usage with a [permissions plugin such as](https://cloudburstmc.org/resources/luckperms.51/) [LuckPerms](https://github.com/LuckPerms/LuckPerms), which is supported on any server that ends with a -kkit*, Spigot, Sponge or Paper.

**This includes Bedrock's Nukkit and Java's Bukkit.*

---

## WitherHosting Helpdesk Article Dump

> ### PocketMine-MP‌
>
> Unlike the other two software PocketMine-MP is written using PHP. It
> was the first form of server software for the Minecraft Bedrock
> community and is currently one of the most used.
>
> #### The Advantages of PocketMine
>
> Since it is the most popular as well as the oldest, it has a lot of
> public plugins which you can use. Compared to the other two softwares,
> PocketMine is not RAM heavy. This means PocketMine uses more CPU
> rather than RAM. For newer developers, there is a great community that
> can help you out with your plugins. Extensive API allowing you to
> change every aspect of how your server behaves.
>
> #### The Disadvantages of PocketMine
>
> PHP is not a widely known or easy to learn language for new
> developers. It would be harder to create plugins for this software
> opposed to other softwares. Lacks most vanilla features, although
> there are plugins that offer some vanilla functionality, most are
> buggy or no longer work.​‌
>
> ### Cloudburst Nukkit
>
> Nukkit is written using Java. It was the second unique form of server
> software for the Minecraft Bedrock community. It isn't the most used
> but is rapidly growing.
>
> #### The Advantages of Nukkit
>
> Just like PocketMine, it also is relatively popular and has a lot of
> public plugins you can use; but not as many as PocketMine offers.
> Compared to the other two softwares, Java is more RAM heavy, meaning
> Java uses more RAM than CPU. Extensive API allowing you to change
> every aspect of how your server behaves. Java is more widespread and
> more friendly for new developers, which makes it easier for new
> developers to start out.
>
> #### The Disadvantages of Nukkit
>
> Compared to PocketMine, it doesn't have as big of a developer
> community. It may be harder to get support for the issues you
> encounter. While Nukkit has more vanilla feature support then
> PocketMine does, the way they are implemented makes them more glitchy
> then a vanilla server.
>
> ### Bedrock Dedicated Server (BDS)
>
> Bedrock Dedicated Server (BDS) is written in C++. It is widely
> considered the official server software for Minecraft: Bedrock
> Edition. This software is relatively new and isn't used as much as the
> previous two.
>
> #### The Advantages of BDS
>
> One of the main and only advantage of BDS is it's ability to have
> every vanilla feature working properly (redstone, mobs, command
> blocks, etc).
>
> #### The Disadvantages of BDS
>
> There isn't any API so writing plugins for this software is not
> possible currently unless you used a modded BDS version. BDS is known
> to be very laggy and sluggish.

Answer (score -1):

You can change their perms where you would normally give them op but instead you click on custom and give them op commands through there. If you only want them to be able to use tp commands, idk.

Comment: Click on custom? I was assuming server commands...