# Teleporting to a location defined by scoreboard objectives

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm currently working on a project and I want to teleport an armor stand to a coordinate which is defined by a scoreboard objective(like if the objective value is 3, the armor stand teleports 3 blocks plus on the X-axis). If the objective name is `Part1Length` and the player name is `w`, how do I get that value into a `/tp` (or `/teleport`) command? Maybe, I can modify the armor stand's data with the `/data` command to increase the `Pos[0]` NBT value, but can I get the scoreboard values from a player's NBT data?
*I work on MC Java Edition 1.15.2*

Comment: This is an example of a very good duplicate. It would be pretty difficult to find https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/339010/171580 without this question, because it uses completely different words, but the solution is still the same (my answer, not the accepted one, I don't know why that other one was accepted). And now your question acts as a new pointer to the solution. Which, BTW, you had almost figured out already, you just didn't know that `/execute store` exists. TLDR of the answer: `/execute store result entity @e[…] Pos[0] double 1 run scoreboard players get […]`