# Teleport entities on values saved in scoreboard

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In Minecraft JE 1.16, I want to make an armor stand teleport to my position, but with an offset. I don't want to include Y position because Y position will change depending if there are blocks in the way.

Currently, I have this code for saving the values:

```
execute store result score @e[tag=TEST] z run data get entity @p Pos[2]
execute store result score @e[tag=TEST] x run data get entity @p Pos[0]
```

And I'm using these commands to make the entity teleport if it is stuck in a block:

```
execute as @e[tag=TEST] at @s unless block ~ ~ ~ air run tp @s ~ ~1 ~
execute as @e[tag=TEST] at @s if block ~ ~-1 ~ air run tp @s ~ ~-1 ~
```

This is all good so far, but I don't know how to move the armour stand based on the scoreboard score. I can't use a normal `/tp` because it will break and then my Y-position of the armor stand also won't work.

Comment: someone help please ?

Comment: Could you teleport the armor stand like this?: `/execute at "Your Name" run tp @e[tag=TEST] ~ ~2 ~` This would tp the armor stand 2 blocks above the player.
You could also just put a fixed number in, `~ 56 ~`

Comment: That is not ideal i want it to teleport Up by block if its in way and i want locked x and z to player like /execute at "Name" run tp @e[tag=TEST] ~3 ~ ~3 but that Y will be changing (for changing y i have commands) that i need is just teleport that entity separatly x and z

Comment: I just need way to TELEPORT entity to Z position 2 blocks from player separatly, same X, and Y

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How do I allow other players on my server to use commands like teleport, but not spawn in items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/321110/how-do-i-allow-other-players-on-my-server-to-use-commands-like-teleport-but-not) (via bypassing duplicate chain from [Teleporting to a location defined by scoreboard objectives](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/364643/185203))